# How to Disable Tap Gesture for Scroll view's sub view?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have created one scrollview for registration. I have also use tableview for drop-down(Male/Female) and tap Gesture on scrollview for hide all input views because touchesBegan method dose not call. whenever i click on table view cell,it will not call didselect method but consider as tap on scrollview.

[image]

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
tap.numberOfTapsRequired=1;
[_scrollview_out addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

Method:-

```
-(void)dismissKeyboard
{
    [_txt_name resignFirstResponder];
    [_txt_mname resignFirstResponder];
    [_txt_surname resignFirstResponder];
    [_txt_gender resignFirstResponder];
    [_txt_dob resignFirstResponder];
    _tbl_view_gender.hidden=true;
    _txt_dob.hidden=false;
    _lbl_dob.hidden=false;

}
```

Table View didSelect Method:-

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [_scrollview_out endEditing:YES];

    str2=[gender_arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    _txt_gender.text=str2;


    _tbl_view_gender.hidden=true;
    _txt_dob.hidden=false;
    _lbl_dob.hidden=false;
}
```

Comment: I want to disable Tap Gesture for just portion of tableview. Or any other optional solution.

Comment: @Hemang Do you mean i have to create registration page in Table view ?

Answer (score 2):

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    if ([touch.view isDescendantOfView:Your Tableview]]) {

        // Don't let selections of auto-complete entries fire the
        // gesture recognizer
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: It is not that what i am want. Thank you for Sharing.

Comment: you can also use  "tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO"

Comment: It is not work for UITableview or UITableviewCell. Touch on tableview(sub view of scrollview) consider as TapGesture's touch.

Answer (score 2):

for me there are two options:

1: add the `tableview` in `scrollView`'s `superView`

2: subclass `UIScrollView`, overwrite method:

```
 -(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch 
{
       //if the touch point in the tableview.
       //return NO;
       //else
       //return YES;
}
```